# Webservice alive forever

Tags: web-services

I often use webservice this way

```
public void CallWebservice()

{

  mywebservice web = new mywebservice();

  web.call();

}
```

but sometimes I do this

```
private mywebservice web;

public Constructor()
{

  web = new mywebservice();

}

public void CallWebservice()
{

  web.call();

}
```

The second approach likes me very much but sometimes it times out and I had to start the application again, the first one I think it brings overhead and it is not very efficient, in fact, sometimes the first call returns a WebException - ConnectFailure (I don't know why).

I found an article ([Web Service Woes (A light at the end of the tunnel?)](http://addressof.com/blog/archive/2004/04/27/Web-Service-Woes-_2800_A-light-at-the-end-of-the-tunnel_3F002900_.aspx)) that exceeds the time out turning the KeepAlive property to false in the overriden function GetWebRequest, here's is the code:

```
Protected Overrides Function GetWebRequest(ByVal uri As System.Uri) As System.Net.WebRequest

  Dim webRequest As Net.HttpWebRequest = CType(MyBase.GetWebRequest(uri), Net.HttpWebRequest)

  webRequest.KeepAlive = False

  Return webRequest

End Function
```

The question is, is it possible to extend forever the webservice time out and finally, how do you implement your webservices to handle this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The classes generated by Visual Studio for webservices are just proxies with little state so creating them is pretty cheap. I wouldn't worry about memory consumption for them.

If what you are looking for is a way to call the webmethod in one line you can simply do this:

```
new mywebservice().call()
```

Cheers